Can the cost of a spell modified by metamagic with the assistance of Improved Metamagic (Su) and Arcane Thesis be reduced to +0?
At 10th level, the Incantatrix (Player's Guide to Faerun, p. 61) gains the following class feature:

Improved Metamagic (Su): At 10th level, an incantatrix has mastered
metamagic to such an extent that whenever she uses a metamagic feat,
the required increase in spell level (if any) is reduced by one
(minimum +1 spell level). For example, a wizard incantatrix could
prepare a quickened fireball as a 6th-level spell instead of a
7th-level spell.
This benefit also applies to the incantatrix's other class abilities.
Thus, the DC for using her metamagic effect or cooperative metamagic
ability is reduced appropriately for the metamagic feats involved, and
she spends fewer charges when using metamagic spell trigger.

The aforementioned class feature is clear that the cost of metamagic cannot be reduced to less than one spell slot above the normal level of the spell being cast. However, how does this class feature interact with feats such as Arcane Thesis, Practical Metamagic, Easy Metamagic, or Metamagic School Focus?
Let us consider the Arcane Thesis feat from Player's Handbook II, p. 74:

Choose one arcane spell that you can cast to be your thesis spell.
When casting that spell, you do so at +2 caster level. When you apply
any metamagic feats other than Heighten Spell to that spell, the
enhanced spell uses up a spell slot one level lower than normal. Thus
if you were to prepare an empowered maximized magic missile (assuming
magic missile is the spell you choose for your Arcane Thesis), it
would be prepared as a 4th level spell (+1 level for empowered, down
from +2; and +2 levels for maximized, down from +3).
A spell cannot be reduced to below its original level with the use of
this feat.

As you can see, the limitation here is defined differently: the spell level cannot drop below the normal level of the spell being cast.
Therefore, how should the interaction between these two features be interpreted? Does Arcane Thesis override the limitation imposed by Improved Metamagic, or does Improved Metamagic impose a restriction on Arcane Thesis?

Addressed in passing in answer to this question, although I think that this question's entitled to standalone.

There is no question of overriding anything. The incantarix’s improved metamagic, as well as the feats Easy Metamagic and Practical Metamagic, have a limitation on their own effect preventing the spell level adjustment from going below +1. Those effects cannot affect a metamagic feat whose adjustment is already +1 or less.
But they don’t apply any “global” restriction or limitation on the affected spell. They are all describing their own effect, and what it won’t do.
And, as you note, other effects don’t have the same limitation. Arcane Thesis has a limitation—in errata, not the published book—that the spell’s overall level cannot be reduced lower than the spell’s original level. Metamagic School Focus doesn’t have any restriction, aside from the 3/day one, so you could arguably apply it to Energy Substitution (normally has no effect on spell level) to reduce a spell’s level (e.g. cold-substituted fireball as a 2nd-level spell).
Each effect is applied separately, and none of these effects directly affect the other. But if you go to apply improved metamagic to a metamagic effect that’s already been reduced to a +1 adjustment, it won’t have any effect, because of improved metamagic’s limitation on its own effect. Contrarily, if improved metamagic reduces a spell adjustment from +2 to +1, and then Arcane Thesis reduces it, it can go from +1 to +0.
So ultimately, this is a question of the ordering of effects: do we apply improved metamagic and then Arcane Thesis, or Arcane Thesis and then improved metamagic? If Arcane Thesis comes later, you can reduce a +2 adjustment to +0. If Arcane Thesis goes first, then you can only get to +1, and improved metamagic won’t do anything. So which is it? There is no rule answering this, but the FAQ suggests “most beneficial order” as a general guideline. That would allow us to choose to use Arcane Thesis last, and reduce a +2 adjustment to +0. But that’s only a guideline, a rule of thumb that the FAQ suggests as a usually-reasonable choice. It’s not remotely strict. Devising another consistent rule is really hard, though.
